# News features from 2.2 to 2.3 version of Android

Tags: 2.2-froyo, 2.3-gingerbread

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's new in Android 2.3 (Gingerbread)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3445/whats-new-in-android-2-3-gingerbread)

Which new changes/features are present on the 2.3 from 2.2 version of Android?

Comment: Where it is duplicatted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The top half of the [Android 2.3 Platform Highlights](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.3-highlights.html) page has a summary of the user-facing changes and new features in Gingerbread.